# Position with JavaScript is not accurate

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Into a php project, I would like to show my current position on a map. Unfortunately, the position is very inaccurate. It deviates by about 20 metres from my actual position.
Can it be more accurate?

```
if(!navigator.geolocation) {
        status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
    } else {
        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
        };

        status.textContent = 'Locating…';
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    }
```

Comment: No. Your location will be as accurate as the device allows it to be.

Comment: GPS is not any more accurate than that, and its accuracy is controlled by the device https://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/